# Tkinter and CherryPy concurrency

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, cherrypy

I am making a program that have a interface using tkinter in the main thread. Once the user click the button run a cherrypy server starts in another thread.

```
...
def startServer():

    class HelloWorld(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def printText(self):
        print("Printing Some Text")
        return {"sucess": "true"}

    cherrypy.config.update({
        'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port': 8080,
    })
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), '/', conf)


def serverExec():

    t = threading.Thread(target=startServer, args=())
    t.start()


root = Tk()
button = Button(top, text="Run", command=serverExec)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to know how can I stop the the Cherrypy thread when I click in a button "Stop". I can't figure out how to communicate with Cherrypy thread, since cherrypy block it in a loop.

Comment: Try calling `cherrypy.engine.exit()` in the callback of the `Stop` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call quickstart. Read its (short!) [code](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/__init__.py#L154) and use the parts you need instead. In this case, just leave off the `engine.block()` call and it won't block (and you won't need to start it in a separate thread).

Then call `engine.stop()` (not `exit`--that's for shutting down the process) from your `Stop` button. Call `engine.start()` again from another button if you like.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept but it really helped. Thank you @fumanchu!